# C#: Implement a abstract property in an interface to implement a child

Tags: c#, class, interface, parent-child, abstract

I couldn't find the answer in the internet so I gonna ask for your help.
I have an abstract class:

```
public abstract class AbstractClass
{
    String Name { get; }        
}
```

Child Class 1:

```
public class ApplicationDetailsModel : AbstractClass
{
   // This will implement unique properties
}
```

And each class that implements IComponent will implement a child of "AbstactClass".

An example implementation:

```
public class ExampleClass : IComponent
{
    public ApplicationDetailsModel DetailsModel;
}
```

And an interface

```
public interface IComponent : IPageViewModel
{
    AbstractClass DetailsModel { get; }
}
```

This example does not compile because the interface forces to implement

AbstractClass DetailsModel = new ApplicationDetailsModel();

Is there a correct way to force an implementation of a child property of a specific abstract class in an interface?

Comment: What is `IComponent`?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Make your interface generic with a constraint

```
public interface IComponent<T> : IPageViewModel
    where T : AbstractClass
{
    T DetailsModel {get;}
}
```

By example:

```
public class ExampleClass : IComponent<ApplicationDetailsModel>{
{
    public ApplicationDetailsModel DetailsModel { get; private set; }
}
```

Comment: It looks like this is the solution I was looking for. Thanks.
I'll try this out and if it works I'll mark this as the accepted answer.